# How to replace 2nd character of a string in a column in r

Tags: r, gsub

Here is an example of a data frame.

```
Type <- c('[C>A]','[C>G]','[C>T]')
Subtype <- c('ACA','ACT','ACC')
df <- cbind(Type, Subtype)
df
     Type    Subtype
[1,] "[C>A]" "ACA"
[2,] "[C>G]" "ACT"
[3,] "[C>T]" "ACC"
```

And this is what I want the output to looks like

```
      Type    Subtype
[1,] "[C>A]" "A[C>A]A"
[2,] "[C>G]" "A[C>G]T"
[3,] "[C>T]" "A[C>T]C"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naïve approach:

```
df[, 2] <- paste0(substr(df[, 2], 1, 1), df[, 1], substr(df[, 2], 3, 3))
df
#       Type    Subtype  
# [1,] "[C>A]" "A[C>A]A"
# [2,] "[C>G]" "A[C>G]T"
# [3,] "[C>T]" "A[C>T]C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
library(stringr)
df[,2] <- str_replace(df[,2],str_split(df[,2],"",simplify = T)[,2],df[,1])

> df
     Type    Subtype  
[1,] "[C>A]" "A[C>A]A"
[2,] "[C>G]" "A[C>G]T"
[3,] "[C>T]" "A[C>T]C"
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `stringr`'s `str_replace` :

```
df[, 2] <- stringr::str_replace(df[, 2], '(?<=.).', df[, 1])
df
#       Type    Subtype  
#[1,] "[C>A]" "A[C>A]A"
#[2,] "[C>G]" "A[C>G]T"
#[3,] "[C>T]" "A[C>T]C"
```

`(?<=)` is positive look-behind regex to match the first character which is not captured, the second dot represents second character which is captured and replaced.

Comment: Hey! can you explain how this is working?

Comment: It works great but I dont know how it works. Could you please explain the regex? Thank you!

Comment: I added an explanation for the regex.